# How to fix 'No source code lines were found at current PC 0x0. Open program memory view to see instruction code disassembly. ' in MplabX

Tags: assembly, embedded, pic, microchip, mplab

I'm using MPLABX v5.25 which is the latest by Microchip. I installed it recently and stumbled upon this error when trying to debug the code. The code written here is a simple assembler code which multiplies two numbers (without overflow).

I tried several methods described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490040/no-source-code-lines-were-found-at-current-pc-0x0) previous question with no effect. The same error occurs every time!

Here's the entire code. The code was written for a [PIC16F877 MCU](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC16F877) and the assembler I used was `mpasm`.

```
processor 16f84a
#include <p16f84a.inc>

int1 equ 0x21
int2 equ 0x22
prod equ 0x23

org 0x00 
start:
    bsf status,5
    movlw b'00000000'
    movwf trisa
    ;movlw b'11111111'
    ;movwf trisb
    bcf status,5

main:
    movlw b'00000101'
    movwf int1
    movlw b'00000010'
    movwf int2

    loop movfw int1
    addwf prod
    decfsz int2
    goto loop
    movfw prod
    movwf porta
    goto $

    end
```

Without debugging successfully the debugger returns,

> Launching
>   No source code lines were found at current PC 0x0.
>   Open program   memory view to see instruction code disassembly.
>   User program stopped
>   User program finished

I can't figure out what the actual problem is. Any advice regarding how to sort this out would be appreciated.

P.S: I tried turning off the watchdog timer using

```
#pragma config WDTE=OFF
```

which returned the same error when debugging.

Comment: What do you see if you open the program memory view as suggested? What do you mean by "Without debugging successfully..."?

Comment: Turn off the watchdog (as you already did) and restart MPLABX

Comment: @the buaybee the PC points to 0. When I pause debugging the PC points to some random value. When the debugger is played again and paused the PC points to some other higher value. All the while showing only ADDWL in the memory.

Comment: @Mike is it a bug in MPLABX?

Comment: Is it mandatory to type the register names in capital? Because when I types the special register names (STATUS,TRISB) in capital the program debugged successfully and I was able to build the hex file.

Comment: It's ONE bug in MPLABX.

Comment: Yes you had to use capital letters, otherwise your file won't compile. Have a look at the pic include file.